# Bitmapdata heavy usage - memory disaster (spark/FB4)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flex4

I've got a flex component which works pretty well but unfortunately turns into a
disaster once used in a datagroup item renderer of about 40-50 items.

Essentially it uses bitmapdata to take screenshot of a fully-rendered webpage in
mx:HTML (this version of webkit rocks btw, miles better than flex 3).

The code is pretty self-explanatory I think.

http://noben.org/show/PageGrabber.mxml

I've optimized it all I could, browsed, search for answers and already trimmed
it down a lot, I'm desparate to reduce the memory usage (about 600mb after 100
draw)

The Garbage collector has little effect.

Thanks!
Nic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `BitmapData.dispose()` when you're done with them, you can't just chuck them away and hope they get collected. Sometimes they will, but often not :'(

Answer (score 2):

would the event listeners be holding on due to strong referance? Try removing listeners or using weak references. See if it helps

Comment: I doubt this would have such an effect. Still, worth knowing about and keeping track of.

Answer (score 1):

Do you ever dispose of `smallBMD`? You might want to make sure they aren't accumulating in memory, lingering around after use, since you create a new one each time the `passoire_completeHandler` is called, without disposing the previous one (as far as I can see).